# How to determine whether the sum ${\sum}_{k=1}^{\infty} {\sin(2^k)\over k}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, summation, upper-lower-bounds

I saw a question on quora asking whether or not the sum ${\sum}_{k=0}^{\infty}{sin(2^k)\over n}$ is convergent.  My opinion, and that of the other answers, is that Dirichlet's test could be used with {$a_{n}$}=$1\over n$ and {$b_{n}$}=$\sin(2^n)$.  I'm lost, however, when it comes to showing whether or not ${\sum}_{k=0}^{\infty}b_n\leq M$ for some $M$.  It was mentioned that an integral test could be used, however, an integral test only works for monotonically decreasing functions, which $\sin(2^x)$ is clearly not.

For those who do not know Dirichlet's convergence test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: If a series converges, its partial sums form a Cauchy sequence.  Do these partial sums form a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: What you mean is that the partial sums $\sum_{k=0}^n b_k$ are bounded.  This is almost certainly not true.

Comment: Is this supposed to be the sum $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin 2^k}{k}$$ ?

Comment: Yes, ultimately the goal is to check the convergence of your mentioned sum (I have edited the question title to reflect this).  However, trying to do this myself led me to question whether or not $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sin(2^k)$ is bounded. An answer or hint to either of both of these questions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you're starting at $k=1$ too

Comment: Yea just changed this also - my bad.

Comment: This could be an open question. I agree with Robert that the Dirichlet's test doesn't look promising. I'd be interested in seeing a solution, but am not very optimistic. The asymptotic behavior of $\sin 2^k$ is pretty hard to describe precisely all I can say is that it's oscillating  between -1 and 1 with an exponentially increasing frequency.

Comment: Circle group reasoning tells us that $\sin 2^k$ will also produces a countable dense subset of $[0,1]$ so I guess that's a little more info. But since the series is not absolutely convergent, even if we just put in 1's and -1's the order they appear is significant

Comment: According to Wolfy, it looks like it converges (1000 terms) to about 0.924965. Perhaps use could be made of $\sin(2^{k+1}) = 2\sin(2^k)\cos(2^k)$ or $\sum \exp(i2^k)/k$.

Comment: isn't this  one of the convergence questions where you need crazy s*it like the irrationality measure of $\pi$ to come even close to a solution?